# How can I validate the string length using java spring validation?

Tags: java, spring, string, validation, spring-validator

I have this field declared in a model class:

```
@Size(min = 2, max = 200, message = "{validation.name.size}")
private String name;
```

where `validation.name.size` is the path to a localized message. The problem is that I do not want to output a message like 'The name is too long or too short.'.

Is there any way to use two different messages and check minimum and maximum string length? `@Min` and `@Max` are only working for numeric types, so they can not be used. What is the alternative for strings?

Comment: Why not "the name must be between 2 and 200 characters"?

Comment: I think this isn't really user friendly. I'd prefer two separat validations.

Comment: Maybe not the most realistic example but as a User I may enter a String size 1. I get, "string to short", now I write "thisisaverylongstring......". And now I get "string to long". Isn't this more annoying than the message provided by @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- ?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You can just use the "@Size"-annotation twice:

```
@Size(min = 2, message = "{validation.name.size.too_short}")
@Size(max = 200, message = "{validation.name.size.too_long}")
private String name;
```

Answer (score 6):

Yes there is - you can use the @Size.List() and @Size annotations in conjunction like so:

```
@Size.List({
     @Size(min = 2, message = "{validation.name.size.too_short}"),
     @Size(max = 10, message = "{validation.name.size.too_long}")
})
```

Answer (score 0):

another option could be to use a regex.
something like

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]]{2,200}$
```

it depends if you want to control the characters.